# How to extract service name from document field in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I am stuck in middle of ELK- Stack configuration, any lead will be highly appreciated.

Case Study:
I am able to see the logs(parsed through logstash without any filter) but I want to apply filter's while parsing the logs.
For ex: 
system.process.cmdline: "C:\example1\example.exe"  -displayname "example.run" -servicename "example.run"

I can see the above logs in kibana dashboard but I want only the -servicename keys, value.
Expected output in Kibana, where servicename is an index and example.run will be associate value.

- servicename "example.run"

I am newbie in ELK.So, Please help me out...

My environment:
Elasticsearch- 6.6
Kibana- 6.6
Logstash- 6.6
Filebeat- 6.6
Metricbeat- 6.6
Logs coming from- Windows server 2016

```
input {
 beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
    grok{
        match =>{"message" => "%{NOSPACE:hostname} "}
    }
}
output {
   file {
     path => "/var/log/logstash/out.log"
  }
}
```

I have tried with the above logstash pipeline. But i am not successfull in getting the required result. Assuming i have to add more lines in filter but don't know what exactly.

Comment: take a reference from below link for filter
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.3/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html

Comment: If you always have `-servicename` and want the value just after, you can use in your grok filter: `-servicename \"%{DATA:servicename}\"`, which would create, for your example, a field `servicename` with value `example.run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in you filter:

```
grok{
       match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:ignore}-servicename \"%{DATA:serviceName}\"" }
}
```

your service name should be now in serviceName key

Comment: `I can see the above logs in kibana dashboard`I think the logs are successfully stored in elasticsearch

Comment: I downvoted when the answer was wrong. Also instead of `%{GREEDYDATA:ignore}`, you can just use `%{GREEDYDATA}`: no field will be created.

Comment: Will this filter will also create a filter name in the Available fields column(left side) on Kibana dashboard?

Comment: yes will create two serviceName and ignore, if you did  not want ignore see the comment from @baudsp